# Record Video By Using Real Sense Front Camera

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, intel, realsense

Am developing desktop application by using real sense SDK . In my application i want to record wham am seeing by the camera / camera viewers. Am using following code the video file has been created. But it now playing in VLC / Windows Media Player. Am using WPF application and C# in visual studio 2013.

Is recording features are possible ?

```
PXCMFaceModule faceModule;
senseManager = PXCMSenseManager.CreateInstance();
senseManager.captureManager.SetFileName("recorded_video.avi", true);
senseManager.EnableStream(PXCMCapture.StreamType.STREAM_TYPE_COLOR, 640, 480, 0);
senseManager.Init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this documentation, guess it will help you ! :
[Realsense doc on raw stream](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/8a/54/intel-realsense-capturing-raw-streams.pdf)

Hope it'll do !